# How to integrate the php’s error codes to submit to a database

Tags: mysql, php, errordocument

I'm trying to writes PHP error to a mysql database. If there’s a way we can change it so that instead of writing directly to an error_log file, it sends the error to a script, which records it in the db.

Comment: What about rsyslog or syslog-ng  ? Send your mysql logs to a syslog server, then setup a filter on it that will intercept php errors and throttle your own script to update your db with the error message. This is the way i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a framework for logging. Log4PHP would also improve your logging over all. It has a MySQL appender.
https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/pdo.html